# Bookmarklet Keeps going to new page

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, bookmarklet

I made this bookmarklet:

```
javascript:(function(){var s=document.createElement('script');s.setAttribute('src','http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js');document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(s);$('#hldIntMain').hide();$('#fadeBackground').hide();return false;})()
```

Formatted code:

```
// Add in jQuery
var s=document.createElement('script');
s.setAttribute('src','http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js');
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(s); 
// Make page viewable
$('#idIntMain').hide();
$('#idBackground').hide();
return false;
```

But whenever I run it, it loads a blank page after doing its work.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the blank page issue, you shouldn't return `false`, and since you are using an auto-invoking anonymous function, you can simply *remove* the `return` statement.

Functions by default, when there is no return statement is on the function body, they return the `undefined` value, and that will prevent navigating to the blank page.

E.g.:

```
javascript:(function () { return false; })();
```

Will show a blank page containing the string representation of the returned value, "false" in this case.

```
javascript:(function () {})();
```

The browser will not navigate.

After that I have a couple of comments:

The file will be loaded asynchronously, you can't be 100% sure that jQuery will be loaded right after changing the `src` attribute of the element, you can use the `load` event of the `script` element (`readystatechange` for IE).

I would also recommend you to append the `script` element to the `head`.